# Python - plt.tight_layout() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib

im trying to run the following code

```
import matplotlib as plt

def plot_filters(layer, x, y):

    filters = layer.get_weights()
    fig = plt.figure.Figure()

    for j in range(len(filters)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(y, x, j+1)
        ax.matshow(filters[j][0], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
        plt.xticks(np.array([]))
        plt.yticks(np.array([]))

    plt.tight_layout()
    return plt

plot_filters(model.layers[0], 8, 4)
```

when running this I am receiving `'module' object is not callable` and it is referencing the `plt.tight_layout()` line.
Cant figure out how to call this. It is present in the matplotlib package.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Try with fig.tight_layout()

Comment: @nsaura unfortunately, when i run `fig=plt.figure()` it gives me the same error but instead it references the `fig=plt.figure()` line,

Comment: yes i misread the question i edited my first comment

Comment: @nsaura that seems to work (i can mark your answer if you post it); umm I have a new error now `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Can you possibly help me with that?

Comment: It's may be because of the return. Try to call p = plot_filters(model.layers[0], 8, 4)

Comment: @nsaura still the same message...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182846/discussion-between-the-brownbatman-and-nsaura).

Comment: Do you have the full traceback ? The line number where it pops out ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have imported the `matplotlib` module itself as `plt`, where you should be importing the `pyplot` module as `plt` instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def plot_filters(layer, x, y):

    filters = layer.get_weights()
    fig = plt.figure()

    for j in range(len(filters)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(y, x, j+1)
        ax.matshow(filters[j][0], cmap = cm.binary)
        plt.xticks(np.array([]))
        plt.yticks(np.array([]))

    plt.tight_layout()

plot_filters(model.layers[0], 8, 4)
```

Comment: i get an additional error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` is there any clue you can give to solve this? thanks! :)

Comment: Where do you get that error? Can you give the full traceback?

Comment: there you go
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\black\Desktop\Uni Work\2018\Sem 2\NIC\Assignment 2\Code\CNN.py", line 84, in <module>
    plot_filters(model.layers[0], 8, 4)
  File "C:\Users\black\Desktop\Uni Work\2018\Sem 2\NIC\Assignment 2\Code\CNN.py", line 20, in plot_filters
    ax.matshow(filters[j][0], cmap = plt.cm.binary)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 7841, in matshow
    nr, nc = Z.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)```

Comment: It's something to do with your data. I don't know what `filters` looks like so can't really say. It should be a 2D array

Comment: yea when I output the weights they show up as a 2D array but I can seem to load them

Comment: In the function `plot_filters` if you print the shape of `filters[j][0]` what is the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182854/discussion-between-the-brownbatman-and-davidg).

Answer (score 0):

try to write it like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def plot_filters(layer, x, y):

    filters = layer.get_weights()
    fig = plt.figure()

    for j in range(len(filters)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(y, x, j+1)
        ax.matshow(filters[j][0], cmap = cm.binary)
        plt.xticks(np.array([]))
        plt.yticks(np.array([]))

    fig.tight_layout()

plot_filters(model.layers[0], 8, 4)
```